# Write a scalar equation of each plane, given its parametric equations

Tags: linear-algebra

> Given:
>   $$x=3-2s+2t$$
>   $$y=1+3s+t$$
>   $$z=5-s-2t$$

I am truly confused, would anybody be able to help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a point, $P(3,1,5)$ and two vectors$V=<2,1,-2>$ and $ W=<-2,3,-1>$ on your plane.

The normal to your plane is the cross product of $V$ and $W$.

Find $ N=V\times W = <a,b,c>$.

The equation of the plane is $$ax+by+cz=d $$ where you can find your $d$ from the given point on the plane.

Comment: How did you find those two vectors?

Comment: $t=0$ gives you one line and $s=0 $gives you another line. The direction vectors of those lines are these vectors.

Comment: Would you be able to show that, if you don't mind.

Comment: The cross product is $<5,6,8>$  and the equation is $5x+6y+8z = 61$

Comment: Would you be able to show how you got the two vectors

Comment: I have answered this question in my first comment above.